# PHP session string contains strange blank/null characters

Tags: php, encoding, amazon-dynamodb, aws-php-sdk

Back story: I've been trying to implement a DynamoDB session handle in my Symfony2 application.

I hit a stumbling block when the session is saved to DynamoDB. It appears the string coming from PHP is in some sort of strange encoding that contains blank characters that aren't whitespace, which then prevents the string from being saved in DynamoDB correctly. The string also doesn't play nice when I paste it into PhpStorm.

Here is a sample of of it:

`$illegalString = 's:8:"userData";O:27:"\SomeClass":49:{s:8:"�*�email";s:27:"me@domain.com";s:13:"�*�first_name";s:4:"Greg";';`

And for reference, here is a screen shot from PhpStorm showing that it isn't whitespace.
[image: PhpStorm Screen shot]
Also, if I try to move my cursor around on those characters, other characters start to appear, in the image below my cursor is a couple of spaces to the left of the last semi colon on line 1, the quotation mark does not exist in the string but for some reason it appears when my cursor is on it.
[image]

If you copy/paste the string above into the site below, it breaks the page: http://www.asciivalue.com/index.php

Three questions:

1. What is wrong with this string? What sort of funky encoding is it?
2. Why is PHP handling session strings this way?
3. How can I tell PHP to only use UTF-8 when creating session strings?

Note: This only appears to happen on AWS ec2 using the latest Linux AMI.

Answer (score 1):

Those characters tell that you have some problem with encodings somewhere (either when converting from one to another (possibly silently) or specifying wrong encoding).

The sequence you have there seems to be `EF BF BD` (as I see it after I've copy-pasted it into UTF-8 document) and it stands for `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` -- used as replacement for illegal characters when converting from one encoding to another (or validating/cleaning up using wrong encoding).

For example: `A0` character is valid in ISO 8599-1, but if you wrongly treat such string as UTF-8 encoded, that character is invalid there and will be replaced by aforementioned sequence.

---

I suggest to check your session data before it gets saved by a session handler (especially if you use custom one) -- maybe it is like that before writing into session.

Also check what session.serialize_handler you are using -- especially if custom one is used.

You can also try writing your own session handler (the part that will write encoded data into file or whatever -- it's easy) -- see what kind of data comes to a handler: is it good or already "corrupted".

I have not used any of the AWS services myself, so cannot advise on this part.